# Can std::function have a function pointer as the type?

Tags: c++, std-function

Suppose that I have the C-style `callback` type like below. For C++, I could create a `std::function` type like `callback2`, and this kind of declaration is all examples I could find. But instead of typing the signature again, can I reuse `callback` like `callback3` below?

If `callback3` is possible,

1. how can I call the callback? Is `c.target<callback>();` like below is the correct way to call the callback?
2. how can I pass a member function? For the common type, I could use `worker2([this]() {toBeCalled();});` but `worker3([this]() {toBeCalled();});` did not work.

Code

```
typedef void (*callback)();
typedef std::function<void()> callback2;
typedef std::function<callback> callback3;

void worker(callback c)
{
    c();
}

void worker2(callback2 c)
{
    c();
}

void worker3(callback3 c)
{
    //Is this the way to call the callback?
    c.target<callback>();
}

class Caller
{
public: Caller()
    {
        //worker2([this]() {toBeCalled();});
        worker3(????);
    }
     void toBeCalled()
    {
         std::cout << "toBeCalled()";
    }
};
```

Comment: I recommend you look at how the standard library handles callable objects: Using *templates*. With a template you can pass just about anything that is callable, like for example a suitable lambda function (which is what I recommend you use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can std::function have a function pointer as the type?

No. The class template `std::function` is defined only for a function type template argument. The template is undefined for all other argument types, including function pointers.

I also recommend against aliasing pointer types in general (there are exceptions to this rule of thumb though). If you avoid it, then you can re-use the alias just fine:

```
typedef void callback();
typedef std::function<callback> callback2;
// or preferably using the modern syntax
using callback  = void();
using callback2 = std::function<callback>;

void worker (callback* c);
void worker2(callback2 c);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`std::remove_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) on `callback`. Let's say your function type is `T` and `callback` is of type `T*`. `std::remove_pointer_t<T*>` would give `T`. In your case `T` is `void()` and `T*` is `void(*)()`.

```
typedef void(*callback)();
typedef std::function<void()> callback1;
typedef std::function<std::remove_pointer_t<callback>> callback2;

void worker(callback c){
    c();
}
void worker1(callback1 c){
    c();
}
void worker2(callback2 c){
    c();
}


int main()
{
    worker([]{std::cout << "callback\n";});
    worker1([]{std::cout << "callback1\n";});
    worker2([]{std::cout << "callback2\n";});
}
/*
Output
callback
callback1
callback2
*/
```

Now, `callback1` and `callback2` are aliases to the same type i.e. `std::function<void()>` in this case.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit: `callback1` and `callback2` are the same type in this example.

Comment: Yes, two aliases to the same type. @eerorika Edited that into the answer.